# Refer to child of dynamically created movieclip actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent-child

So this is how I add a movieclip dynamically

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName('some_name') as Class;
myBody = new ClassReference();
myBody.name = "curtheme"; // I am giving it an instance name here
addChild(myBody);
```

then I have many children of this dynamically added movie clip

```
var hair:Array = [curtheme.getChildByName('hair1'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair2'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair3'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair4'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair5'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair6'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair7'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair8')]; 

var top:Array = [curtheme.getChildByName('top1'), curtheme.getChildByName('top2'), curtheme.getChildByName('top3'), curtheme.getChildByName('top4'), curtheme.getChildByName('top5'), curtheme.getChildByName('top6'), curtheme.getChildByName('top7'), curtheme.getChildByName('top8')];
```

this gives error: Access of undefined property curtheme. Obviously this is wrong but then how do I access its children by name? I hope my question is straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
var curtheme:DisplayObjectContainer = this.getChildByName('curtheme') as DisplayObjectContainer;

var hair:Array = [curtheme.getChildByName('hair1'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair2'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair3'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair4'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair5'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair6'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair7'), curtheme.getChildByName('hair8')];
var top:Array = [curtheme.getChildByName('top1'), curtheme.getChildByName('top2'), curtheme.getChildByName('top3'), curtheme.getChildByName('top4'), curtheme.getChildByName('top5'), curtheme.getChildByName('top6'), curtheme.getChildByName('top7'), curtheme.getChildByName('top8')];
```

or instead of:
`curtheme.getChildByName('hair1')`

try

`var hair:Array = [ this['curtheme']['hair1'], this['curtheme']['hair2'], this['curtheme']['hair3'], ...];`